# Escape single quote from last name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have ajax call in my jQuery code with which I am doing lookup with C# web method.

The call works normally most of the time, the user needs to enter last name and it will get all the results for that last name.

The problem happens when user will enter last name with single quote included such as ***O'leary***.

**This is the jQuery line I am using:**

```
   data: "{selectedAgent: '" + $('#<%=txtAgentNameText.ClientID %>').val() + "', 
   companyID: '" + $('#<%=ddlCompany.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
```

The problem happens with the `txtAgentNameText.ClientID` value.

Comment: where is your escaping code? for any escape character can use `\`before them.

Comment: what exactly is this problem that happens?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are passing a JSON string to your jQuery ajax method. Why not just pass a javascript object?

```
var data = {
            selectedAgent:$('#<%=txtAgentNameText.ClientID %>').val(),
            companyID: $('#<%=ddlCompany.ClientID %>').val()
           };

$.ajax({...data:data...})
```

Comment: you could create the JSON object in the  `$.ajax()` call as well.

Comment: I believe that would change the request to pass URL-encoded values instead of JSON. If you want to keep JSON, you can take that data and stringify it (`JSON.stringify(data)`), and pass that string in. Just make sure you either are targeting newer browsers, or include `json2.js` in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the escape character  is \ so you could replace  \' or you could change your format so the last name is contained in double quotes! Both ways should suffice

Comment: Both ways should suffice, unless you get some weird name with a double quote in it :) (then think of all the fun xss attacks the person could have). It's best to just escape the quote character that it is contained in.

Comment: Oh never thought of that actually